# evitar que los botones next y prev carousel bootstrap 4 se desplacen verticalmente

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Tengo un carousel con una lista oculta que con un botón con javascript se expande la lista y al hacer esto. Se desplazan los iconos de prev y next hacia abajo y cuando oculto la lista los iconos vuelven a subir. como evitar que los botones se desplacen con la lista?

```js
$('#mostrar1').click(function()
    {
     $("#ciberguridad").show("swing");
      $("#mostrar1").hide();
      $("#ocultar1").show();
      $("#curso-1").height(1090);
    });
    
    
$('#ocultar1').click(function()
{
  $("#ciberguridad").hide("swing");
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#curso-1").offset().top
    },1000);
  $("#mostrar1").show();
  $("#ocultar1").hide();
  $("#curso-1").height(700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div id="curso-1" class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="assets/img/curso-1.jpg" class="curse center-block" alt="">
           <h3>uyhttghgggggg</h3>
           <p class="parafo-curso">Ckljljljljljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjhgjhfgjhg</p>
           <ul id="ciberguridad">
            <li>lkjljljlj</li>
            <li>lkjjlkjljlj</li>
            <li>lkjlkjljlj (GMT-6)</li>
            <li>lkjljlj</li>
            <li>jklkljljljljl <a target="_blank" href="">Linkedin</a></li>
            <li>Requisitos: N/A</li>
            <li>Metodología: Streaming Live.</li>
            <li>Cupo limitado.</li>
            <li>kjhkljlkjkljljlj.</li>
            <li>jlkjlkj: <a>Descargar</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
            <button type="button"  id="mostrar1"  class="btn btn-primary">Leer más </button>
            <button type="button"  id="ocultar1"  class="btn btn-primary">Cerrar </button>
           </div>
         <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <!-- <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> -->
           <span class="iconos"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <!-- <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> -->
          <span class="iconos"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
       </div>
```

Comment: Y donde quieres que se queden los botones? al expandirse la lista los botones se mueven abajo para no ser tapados por la lista

Comment: Pon los botones antes que la lista. ¿Puedes hacer modificaciones al código?, si puedes tocar el css puedes decirle position absolute para sacarlo del flujo, a la lista quiero decir, y darle un z-index superior al de los botones previous next, asi se pondra por encima sin desplazarlos.